# Why AJAX is showing me a JSON file which I have returned through view function in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

I'm using flask as a backend and I have a button and with the use of AJAX, I am calling a view function in the flask. and I have created a son file to store some data of form.

when I fill the form and press the button my function upload gets called and it creates results and pushes it to the JSON file.
I'm returning this JSON file so that I can display it to the frontend dynamically.
but instead of data, I'm getting the whole JSON file.

upload view calls api/test to generate messages and add that messages to the data.json file

I have used ajax and a similar function in my other project but never occurred this error.

Here is my form and ajax code.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#upload').on('click', 'button', function () {
       
            let photos_fd = new FormData()
            var img = document.getElementById('photos').files.length;
            if (img == 0) {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red">Select at least one file</span>');
                return;
            }
            console.log(document.getElementById('photos').files[0])

            for (var x = 0; x < img; x++) {
                photos_fd.append("photos[]", document.getElementById('photos').files[x]);
            }
            
            let formData = new FormData()
                formData.append("email", $('#email').val());
                formData.append("label", $('#label').val());

                console.log("you submit the form", $('#email').val(), $('#label').val() );

                $.ajax({
                    url: " {{url_for('upload')}} ",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    photos : photos_fd,
                    type: '',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("xxxxxxx");
                        alert(data.keys());
                        // console.log("",response);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        $("#msg").text(response.response); // display error response
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-clean">
        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2 class="text-center">Upload Image</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control is-invalid" type="email"  id='email' name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="label" name="label" placeholder="Image Name">
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" id="photos" name="photos[]">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button id ="upload" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">UPLOAD</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

flask view
upload

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
  if 'photos[]' in request.files:
  photos = request.files.getlist('photos[]')
  photo = photos[0]

  label = request.form["label"]
  email = request.form["email"]

  img_formate = "." + str(photo.filename).split(".")[-1] 

  image = label + img_formate
  photo.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image))

  result = {
     label:
     {
        'image': image,
        'email': email,
        'caption': json.loads(response.text)['message']
     }
  }

  with open('templates/data.json') as f:
     data = json.load(f)

  data.update(result)

  with open('templates/data.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(data, f,indent=4)

  if photo.filename != '':
     return data
```

else:
      return redirect(url_for('index'))

I'm getting JSON file like this on clicking the button.
I expect the returned JSON object to be printed to the screen underneath the form, but instead, the data returned is printed directly to the browser window, which doesn't maintain the structure of 'index.html' (which has navbars and a form). I am returned this::

```
{
    "img1": 
    {
    "caption": " a man holding a dog in a white shirt ", 
    "email": "m@gmail.com", 
    "image": "img1.jpg"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing your code here I found error:
1. In the Second line of the script, it should be #form instead of #Upload
2. You haven't mentioned type in Ajax Call

Given bellow is modified javascript code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let photos_fd = new FormData()
            var img = document.getElementById('photos').files.length;
            if (img == 0) {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red">Select at least one file</span>');
                return;
            }
            console.log(document.getElementById('photos').files[0])

            for (var x = 0; x < img; x++) {
                photos_fd.append("photos[]", document.getElementById('photos').files[x]);
            }
            
            let formData = new FormData()
                formData.append("email", $('#email').val());
                formData.append("label", $('#label').val());

                console.log("you submit the form", $('#email').val(), $('#label').val() );

                $.ajax({
                    url: " {{url_for('upload')}} ",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    photos : photos_fd,
                    type: 'POST', 
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("xxxxxxx");
                        alert(data.keys());
                        // console.log("",response);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        $("#msg").text(response.response); // display error response
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: thank you @imrankhan for helping me out. it worked thanks.